# Read a URL in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, webserver, raspberry-pi

I want to read data present in a URL. For example if I had this URL:

http://robolab.in/home-automation.html#ON

I want to read the status 'ON', leaving behind the rest of the URL. How can this be done?

Comment: So do you want to get the content of the response to this Webpage or just parse the URL in order to get the status `ON`? What do you mean by _get the URL_? Where does this URL come from since you need to know it in order to either parse or analyze its response?

Comment: This is my company's website and I have created a html page.Where,I have a button which when clicked changes the text ON and OFF. so,I want to read the status of ON and OFF on the link itself rather reading the data inside the link.I mean ,I want to continuosly check whether it is ON or OFF .If it is OFF the link automatically changes to :http://robolab.in/home-automation.html#OFF. so, please provide me a solution such that by reading a single link ,I must be able to check the status by the link itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to do is called web scraping. In python using urllib/urllib2 library you can achieve this goal.

```
import urllib

try:
    html=urllib.urlopen('http://robolab.in/home-automation.html#ON')
    htmltext=html.read()
except:
    print 'error opening link'

print htmltext
```

this prints the html text that your browser shows you.
now this is just a string... you can manipulate it anyway you want.
But if you have BeautifulSoup installed you can code something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
text = soup.get_text()
print text
```

using this code and given your url I got this:

```
Robolab Technologies
Home Automation

OFF
```

and you can easily proceed

```
status=''
text=text.strip()
for index,line in enumerate(text):
    if index>3:
        status = line
if 'ON' in status:
    print "it's on"
else:
    print "it's off"
```

Comment: hi,thanks.but i want to check only whether it is ON or OFF then what more should i include to do so.

Comment: that's the easy part.. You as the programmer should code this part, but I'll edit my answer.